# CSS3 Multiple Cubes

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to having multiple rotating cubes in a single container. On adding float value to the cube, the rotation of the cube is changed as a result of which the **cube rotates in a slightly titled direction**.

Right now the cubes are rotating an angle, It appears as if I'm looking at them from sideways. I want them to rotate in X direction without the tilt that is currently there (as if I'm directly infront of the face).

Please check the code here - http://codepen.io/iakshay/pen/iFhLH

Comment: What's the question, exactly? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that the center of your div simply is not where you expect it to be.

Your container has a width of 100% while your cubes only cover a few hundred pixels.

Depending on what you want to do (not clear from the question) either narrow your container or offset your cubes.